# "This way" or "like that" or "thus"-- which is most natural?

Tags: word-choice

Here are three sentences:

> Take the prescribed pills and **this way** you will be fit very soon.

> Take the prescribed pills and **like that** you will be fit very soon.

> Take the prescribed pills and **thus** you will be fit very soon.

Which of these sounds most natural to a native speaker?

Comment: None of them is very idiomatic. _In that way_ is the most likely if you must use a phrase like that, but I think most speakers would just say _and you will be fit very soon_.

Comment: Why do you need anything there in the first place? "Take the prescribed pills and (eventually) you will be fit very soon."

Comment: "thus" is usually used in writing. In your context, we'd say " and that way" etc.

Comment: Pills do not make people fit. Diet and exercise do.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, "thus" tends to be used in relatively formal writing rather than in speech or informal writing. Used as a conjunction, it indicates result.

"Like that" has several meanings but does not indicate cause. The normal way that your sentence with "like that" would be interpreted in the US is "almost immediately." So it does not mean what I think you want to say. Furthermore, it is quite informal.

"In this way" can indicate "result."

Therefore, "thus" and "in this way" could be used to indicate cause and effect, but I agree with the comments that the relationship is so obvious that neither would typically be used.